# reatcJS - Make API call and Store data in New File with .JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, reactjs

Hi I have react admin template and I am trying to input API resulted JSON data to the sample tables given in template.

Currently
The table is fetching manually entered data from ../assets/api/tables/datatables.standard.json

The table is located in 
../app/routes/tables/Datatables.js

Code:

```
    <WidgetGrid>


      <div className="row">
        <article className="col-sm-12">



          <JarvisWidget editbutton={false} color="blueDark">
            <header>
              <span className="widget-icon"> <i className="fa fa-tasks"/> </span>
              <h2>Task List and Status</h2>
            </header>
            <div>
              <div className="widget-body no-padding">

                <Datatable
                  options={{
                    ajax: 'assets/api/tables/datatables.standard.json',
                    columns: [
                      {data: "id"},
                      {data: "aliasName"},
                      {data:"author"},
                    {data: "action"},

                      {data: "updatedAt"},
                      {data: "lastRanAt"},
                      {data:"nextRunAt"},
                      {data: "status"},
                      {data:"scheduleEnabled"}
                    ],
                    buttons: [
                      'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
                    ]
                  }}
                  className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                  width="100%">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th data-hide="mobile-p">Job UID</th>
                    <th data-hide="mobile-p">Task Name</th>
                      <th data-hide="mobile-p">Author</th>
                    <th data-hide="mobile-p">Action</th>
                        <th data-hide="mobile-p,tablet-p">Updated at</th>
                    <th data-hide="mobile-p,tablet-p">Last executed</th>
                    <th data-hide="mobile-p">Next execution</th>
                    <th data-hide="mobile-p">Current Status</th>
                      <th data-hide="mobile-p">Schedule Enabled</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                </Datatable>

              </div>
            </div>
          </JarvisWidget>
        </article>


      </div>

    </WidgetGrid>
```

Here is my question:

I am using reactjs and How can I make an API call to store the data in to '../assets/api/tables/datatables.standard.json' file

where I currently entered data manually inside datatables.standard.json file.

Let me know where can I run that API code? Is it app.js or I should create some new file with JS extension or JSX extension. I am confused with so many answers across internet

Please help. Thanks,

- Chaitu